# Does Clang support `-g1`

Tags: clang

I found an old mailing list thread about this [here](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-April/048821.html), however, not any further info nor anything in the documentation.

Does Clang support that flag? I tried `-g1`, `-g2`, `-g3` and `-g` on a sample but the result was always the same, so it looks like it does not.

Is that planned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently `clang` does not, but it's not very well documented.  Although it accepts the options you've mentioned it treats them all as though they had been `-g`.  From the clang source code, `llvm/tools/clang/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp` comes this code (on about line 2825 of rev 205900):

```
  // Use the last option from "-g" group. "-gline-tables-only" and "-gdwarf-x"
  // are preserved, all other debug options are substituted with "-g".
  Args.ClaimAllArgs(options::OPT_g_Group);
  if (Arg *A = Args.getLastArg(options::OPT_g_Group)) {
    if (A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_gline_tables_only)) {
      // FIXME: we should support specifying dwarf version with
      // -gline-tables-only.
      CmdArgs.push_back("-gline-tables-only");
      // Default is dwarf-2 for darwin.
      if (getToolChain().getTriple().isOSDarwin())
        CmdArgs.push_back("-gdwarf-2");
    } else if (A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_gdwarf_2))
      CmdArgs.push_back("-gdwarf-2");
    else if (A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_gdwarf_3))
      CmdArgs.push_back("-gdwarf-3");
    else if (A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_gdwarf_4))
      CmdArgs.push_back("-gdwarf-4");
    else if (!A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_g0) &&
             !A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_ggdb0)) {
      // Default is dwarf-2 for darwin.
      if (getToolChain().getTriple().isOSDarwin())
        CmdArgs.push_back("-gdwarf-2");
      else
        CmdArgs.push_back("-g");
    }
  }
```

As you can see by the last few lines, any `-g` option which hasn't already been eliminated (e.g. `-g7`) gets transformed into a plain `-g` within this routine, `Clang::ConstructJob()`.

I don't know of any plans to change this, but I'm also not a clang developer.  You might want to ask on the mailing list.

See [the online manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-size-of-debug-information) for the documented switches, and [the source code for Tools.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp) to look at the rest of the option handling in detail.